# how to build rails running environment on FreeBSD 9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation, freebsd

I know two methods:

#### Method 1: Install rails with ports, steps are:

1. install ruby,lang/ruby19
2. install gem, devel/ruby-gems
3. install rails, www/rubygem-rails

#### Method 2: Install rails with gem (same on Mac OS X):

1. install ruby,lang/ruby19
2. install gem, devel/ruby-gems
3. install rails, gem install rails

method 1 works well, but I want to try method 2, finish all steps of method2, I try to create my first app with command `rails new hello`, but failed, errors are followed:

**What's the best method building rails development/running environment on FreeBSD 9.1?**

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:628:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:570:in `connection_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:930:in `request'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:195:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:169:in `use_api'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `select'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:162:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not install Ruby from your package manager, prefer [RBEnv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to handle this job. To use it on FreeBSD:

```
# as root
pkg_add -r bash curl git libxml2 libxslt node-devel sqlite3 sudo wget

# as user

# rbenv
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile

# ruby and rails
rbenv install 2.4.4
rbenv global 2.4.4
gem install rails
```

I hope this will help you :)

Source: http://chatchan.us/bsdonrails.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Not able to reproduce that. Update your ports tree and try again, perhaps you need the new version of devel/ruby-gems.

Comment: thanks, what's your os version, I guess wrong openssl version was used. now I install rvm first, and then update openssl, then install ruby with `rvm install 2.0.0`, it works. BTW, since rvm use bash, so I installed bash before installing rvm.

Comment: FreeBSD 9.0 is what I used to test. I could setup 9.1 to test too. Did you install anything else before trying to install rails? Also, it would be helpful to post the output of pkg_info and gem list.

Comment: I install lang/ruby2.0 and devel/ruby-gem from ports first, then try to install rails with gem from ports (gem install rails), its works. but bundle command always fail to execute. when I use rvm, I install openssl with rvm (rvm pkg install openssl), then everything will be fine.

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce, but until then, you might also consider trying the www/rubygem-rails port.

Comment: I reinstall lang/ruby20, then add `WIHT_OPENSSL_PORT=yes` into Makefile, then execute `bundle install`, the follow errors arise, _Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
        troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks! /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0/net/http.rb:917:in 'connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)_, then I replace `source 'https://rubygems.org'` in Gemfile into `source 'http://rubygems.org'`, bundle works well.

Answer (score 0):

Habax hit it on the head. I'd upvote you but this is a new account. Sorry!

Because I use a bash shell: .profile = .bash_profile

Newest ruby version installs correctly. Takes 5 min or so to install though.

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

For compatibility and possibly stability, we are using rails 3.2.13 instead of 4.0.0.

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
```

Answer (score 0):

As root install prebuilt packages:

```
pkg install ruby27-gems rbenv
gem install rails
```